# Как можно создать такую инфраструктуру через Yandex Maps?

Tags: яндекс-карты

каким образом можно создать такую инфрастуктуру. Ключевая особенность в том что он из списка выше выбирает что ему надо и появляется на карте. Заранее спасибо.
https://krasnogorskiy-ndv.ru/location.html

Answer (score 0):

Через фильтрацию. Готовые примеры от самого !
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoobjects_menu